# Caching a paginated request, and evicting data

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm building a web service using Spring. One paginated request has as parameters the *userID*, the *page* number of the request, and the *size* of the page. I want to cache the response to this request. Basically I have

```
@Cacheable(value="foo", key="{#userId,#page,#size}")
public Bar getPaginatedResponse(String userId, int page, int size) {
...}
```

This part works fine. The problem is that I have another request which changes the user data. When I call it, I have to evict **all** the cache entries for that *userId*, no matter the *page* and *size* parameter.

```
public Baz updateUser(String userId, String data) {
...}
```

Obviously I cannot use @CacheEvict because it makes an exact match of the parameter. Is there a solution using convenient libraries or do I have to write everything myself?

---

I used foo, bar, baz in place of the actual classes and names. I don't *think* it matters for the cache question if I return a ResponseEntity> or a simple object. So far I'm using ehcache 3.0.0, but that is easy to change. Using something other than Spring is not practical.

Comment: Can you not rework your API such that you can provide the page and size?  Since your entity is cached with those as part of the key, it would make sense from a cache eviction standpoint to evict those values since the key had changed (likely, the page and size would be 0 instead of any value you had set prior).

Comment: @Makoto, the update function may change the content of the paginated list. So if the user views five entries per page, then ten entries per page, causes the update, and then views five entries per page, the paginated response for *five* entries must be recalculated despite the fact that the UI was showing *ten* entries when the update happened.